# How to add custom cursor after clicking on button, and save it to LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I press a button, I want the cursor to change to a custom image using a URL, and after refreshing or changing the page I want it to still be customized.

My code:

```
let cursor1 = document.getElementById("cursor1"); //my button
```

and I tried this:

```
var sheet = (function () {
  // Create the <style> tag
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return style.sheet;
})();
cursor1.onClick () => {
   sheet.insertRule("body { cursor: 'url(cursor3.png)', auto; }", 0);
}
```

But it doesn't work at all, same with this:

```
cursor1.onclick = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("cursor", "url(cursor3.png), auto");
  location = self.location;
};

window.onload = function () {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");
  var cursor1 = localStorage.getItem("cursor");
  body.style.cursor = cursor1;
  window.location.reload;
};
```

When I did something like this it changes cursor to custom, but return to default after refreshing the page:

CSS:

```
html
{
    cursor: default;
}
html.help
{
    cursor: url('cursor3.png');
}
```

JS:

```
function change()
{
    $("html").toggleClass("help")
}
```

Comment: `body { cursor: url('cursor3.png'), auto; }` url doesn't need to be wrapped in quotes, only the image name

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: `document.getElementById("cursor1")` Where is your element with an id of `cursor1`? It is not in your HTML.

Comment: It is in my HTML. Button got id ='cursor1'